# Microsoft Example 52 -

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I managed to get Microsoft Example 52 to work last friday. But after the weekend (from 13. January on) I get the following error:

Error refreshing OpenId configuration:
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration'.
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync()
at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.JwtTokenExtractor.ValidateTokenAsync(String jwtToken, String channelId, String[] requiredEndorsements)
...
Error refreshing OpenId configuration: System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration'.
---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration'.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:  connection attempt failed because the remote peer did not respond properly after a certain period of time, or the established connection was faulty because the connected host did not respond.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the remote terminal did not respond properly after a certain period of time, or the established connection was faulty because the connected host did not respond

-> By the way I translated the last two exceptions with deepl as they where in German

I already checked the forum and also documentation but with no luck.
Today I tried the example from scratch with different bot, different bot channels registration, and new copied example project but I still get the same error.

I still have to mention: The only difference to documentation is, that I registered bot and channel registration with another my azure user. And in teams I use an other account with office 365 business basic license. But last week it has worked - so maybe that's no problem at all!?!

Does anyone has an idea what to try next?

Comment: Where is your bot hosted?

Comment: Hi, it is hosted on my webservice, not in azure. I just did the bot channels registration.

Comment: During debugging of my bot with Visual Studio I can step into BotController.cs. The error occurs in PostAsync() after  'await Adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, Bot);'

Comment: ok, good to know, that's why I asked - if it's hosted on your own infrastructure, are you 100% it has outbound internet access? It needs to be able to physically call out to https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration . That might be fine on your local dev workstation, but blocked on an internal company server, for instance.

Comment: With internet access nothing has changed. When I go to the link provided I get following result:
issuer "https://api.botframework.com"
authorization_endpoint "https://invalid.botframework.com"
jwks_uri "https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/keys"
id_token_signing_alg_values_supported 
0 "RS256"
token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported 
0 "private_key_jwt"

Comment: yes, but your running code needs to be able to download that, at runtime

Comment: So maybe "authorization_endpoint "https://invalid.botframework.com"" is a problem?

Comment: no, I don't think so, it still sounds like your code is struggling to actually access that endpoint...

Comment: Ok, I added to my BotController.cs 'var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration");'
This just should download the json, like I did in browser. My bot now gets at this point System.Net.WebException (Timeout).

Comment: so you don't need to download it yourself - the jwt token validation will do that itself, but the fact that you're hitting the same issue once again makes me think there's something blocking the internet access - either the server it's running on, or the account it's running under, or missing proxy settings perhaps for one of those.

Comment: Hm, I understand what you mean. I created two new projects on my host (one with .net framework and one with .net core 3.1). Well, the one with .net framwork downloads the json. The .net core project has a timeout. Proxy is set on both... I will continue to research in this direction and report back when I have found the problem.

Comment: Sounds like an important lead!

Comment: So, problem is found: timeout exception was because of a strange proxy configuration script - and .net framework and .net core used different proxy connection settings so one could access the url the other one not.
@HiltonGiesenow: thanks for your input and help. If you formulate your 2. post as answer I could mark my question as answered :)

Comment: Done. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments above, this sounded like an issue with how the bot was hosted, and jwt validation code not being able to call out to the internet (e.g. a security or proxy setting). It needs to be able to physically call out to login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration . That might be fine on a local dev workstation, but blocked on an internal company server, for instance. In the end it was something in this line - proxy settings blocking the outgoing call, so listing it here as an answer for future visitors.